# Salesforce Marketing Cloud: How to restrict access to All Subscriber from Child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, automationstudio

We have Production BU and UAT BU in our implementation,We want our developer not to access All Subscriber in UAT BU because of PII issue.

I can control it with Custom role with deny access to All Subscriber but Developer can create a Automation SQL and get those Production PII(All Subscriber) in a Data extension.

Anyone has idea how to implement it without impacting Development work?